# Add a Description to Attribute (for Screen Reader) Without Adding New Label / Element

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I have the element: `<div id="container-div" role="region"></div>`

When the user will click the key 'R' I want the screen reader reads the words

"this is XXX area region"

without adding new label or element in the DOM.

(It's really important to keep the DOM clean without an extra hidden labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `aria-label` attribute, like this:

```
<div id="container-div" role="region" aria-label="This is an XXX">
```

Tip: don't use the word Region in your description since screen readers (at least JAWS) add it themselves. So, if you write "This is an XXX area region", a screen reader would say "This is an XXX area region region" because of the role.

Comment: Hi, the 'region' aria-label' inside 'textarea' is not working for me, suggestion?

Comment: Region inside a textarea? How in the world is this possible? :) Could you provide some code, please?)

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë technically with ARIA, you can make anything anything, if the role is defined. Does it make sense, nope. OP try `<textarea aria-label="xxx">`

Comment: <textarea role="region" aria-label="text area"></textarea>. It's good if I need few main regions in the page, and one of them is the text area.

Comment: Nope nope. If you want this, you have to wrap your textarea in a div. As far as I know, screen readers can't process a form element as a separate region, it's mainly for div-like elements.